# How do I replace content with other content in a Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am iterating over my model and I wanted to replace that list with content from same model, only sorted, just by using a button. Let's presume I have this:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button>Replace content </button>
</div

<div class="col-md-9">
 {% for c in cats%}
     {{c.name}}
 {% endfor %}
 <p>Content to be replaced</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
 {% for c in animal.cats_set.all %}
     {{c.name}}
 {% endfor %}
 <p>Content to replace above content, sorted by if cat belongs to same animal</p>
</div>
```

How would I replace the content with the second content in this case ? Im thinking about a jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.replaceWith()` function. Like:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button>Replace content </button>
</div

<div class="col-md-9 old">
 {% for c in cats%}
     {{c.name}}
 {% endfor %}
 <p>Content to be replaced</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9 new">
 {% for c in animal.cats_set.all %}
     {{c.name}}
 {% endfor %}
 <p>Content to replace above content, sorted by if cat belongs to same animal</p>
</div>
```

Your jQuery function will be:

```
$(function() {

  $(":button").click(function(e) {
     $(".old").replaceWith($(".new"));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw out a warning first: deciding on whether you want the data changed by the Django template player or JQuery are two very different things.

Django will change the data on the server, while JQuery is used to change rendered data (usually after the page has already been displayed to the user).

**Going the Django Route:**

Django is only a template player, so you cannot change it after it has been rendered.  It is not a functional language which can continually interact with a rendered page.

You can, however, use the template syntax to put logic in place to decide where data will go or use a structure such as [the Django Blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

```
{% block blockName %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

When I'm writing a complex template I often find myself using this structure:

```
{% extends "path/ParentFile.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "path/ToDefaultChildFile.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you're ok with the page rendering and then changing it with JQuery once the page is loaded then you'll want to look into the JQuery/JavaScript/frontend framework code to do so.

Comment: I want that after the data is loaded, the content to be changed by jQuery. I just don't know how to do it..

Comment: Well, again, it's worth considering whether it would really just be easier to figure out how to change your template before it has been rendered.  You might be able to make including JavaScript totally unnecessary.  However, if you are set on using JavaScript you'll need to do things such as access the element with a selector $('myselector') and then replace the content possibly with something like innerHTML - but all of this is more than a comment and you ought to accept this answer so we can close it and then check out some JQuery tutorials to get yourself going. :)

Comment: extends did the trick, thank you! :-)